# Using Etherscan API to get the Token ID of a transaction

Tags: etherscan

Currently, I am using [Etherscan API](https://etherscan.io/apis) to get the list of all transactions from a specific wallet using the endpoint: https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=WALLET_ADDRESS&sort=asc&apikey=MY_API_KEY

Once I find the transaction I'm looking for from that endpoint, I get the transaction hash (lets just say **0x92df276c29cb3cbc77487ef5531a64fac9dc13b1d5fdf7d20fc41bc0830badfc** for this example).

I am then using the [etherscan-api](https://sebs.github.io/etherscan-api/#eth_gettransactionbyhash) **eth_getTransactionByHash** function to get the transaction details using the above hash, however the response does not contain the Token ID which I then intend to use to gather more information about the purchase.

The Token ID for this transaction is 1037 as seen here: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x92df276c29cb3cbc77487ef5531a64fac9dc13b1d5fdf7d20fc41bc0830badfc

**The response I get:**

```
{
  jsonrpc: '2.0',
  id: 1,
  result: {
    blockHash: '0x109f379a8d9febf029c78a1fb755c609713028f59404925a5cf489dd7e3e9810',
    blockNumber: '0xc88e66',
    from: '0x5ea9681c3ab9b5739810f8b91ae65ec47de62119',
    gas: '0x4d53e',
    gasPrice: '0xfc49b4261',
    maxFeePerGas: '0x16a8ea23bb',
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: '0x59682f00',
    hash: '0x92df276c29cb3cbc77487ef5531a64fac9dc13b1d5fdf7d20fc41bc0830badfc',
    input: '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',
    nonce: '0x36f',
    to: '0x7be8076f4ea4a4ad08075c2508e481d6c946d12b',
    transactionIndex: '0x12a',
    value: '0xbcbce7f1b150000',
    type: '0x2',
    accessList: [],
    chainId: '0x1',
    v: '0x1',
    r: '0x6c2a67f4f5de28576d3128f1c132c82c6dc6303736c8262790d2a32d02a127ca',
    s: '0x7bb4031c9e2ac1890ee30e7f835fcb49358036ded27bc18144dead4cab47ac09'
  }
}
```

Is there anyway I can gather the Token ID from the information provided in the response? Or failing that is there some other API I can call?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can use ABI ERC721 or get from 'event log'

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide some example how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API endpoint for Ropsten Network. It will provide you all the details with token.

https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokennfttx&address=<your_Contract_Address>&startblock=0&endblock=latest&sort=asc&apikey=<your_API_key>

I am using Ropsten API because my contract is deployed on Ropsten Testnet. You can adjust block with your starting block.